# How can I append a user_id to the end of a URL in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, routes

I'm creating a report table for each user in my database that logs dates/times. Here's my controller:

```php
public function create()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    return view('report.create', compact('user'));
}

public function show($id) 
{
    $data = Time::findOrFail($id);

    return view('report.show', compact('data'));  
}
```

So right now if I go to `/reports/1`, it'll only give me access to the times data with an id of one. However, I want it so if I go to `reports/1`, i'll have access to all the times data for the user with a user_id of 1.

I tried doing the following, but it didn't work and gave me a 404 on every /# page.

```php
public function show(Time $time) 
{
    $data= Time::findOrFail($time->user_id)

    return view('report.show', compact('data'));  
}
```

Here's my routes for 'reports':

```php
Route::resource('reports', 'ReportController');
```

And here's my times DB migration that i want to use the data from:

```php
Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->date('start_day');
    $table->text('category');
    $table->time('start_time');
    $table->time('finish_time');
    $table->time('duration');
    $table->text('notes');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you only need to modify the show controller like this

```
public function show($id) 
{
    $data = Time::where('user_id',$id)->get();

    return view('report.show', compact('data'));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the route parameter. It also looks like you have some auto wiring issues.

```
Route::resource('reports/{id}', 'ReportController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$data= Time::findOrFail($time->user_id);
```

to

```
$data= Time::where('user_id','=',$time->user_id)->get();
```